# An unjustified bound in calculation of polynomial resultants

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, resultant

In an endeavor to prove Bezout's theorem for algebraic plane curves, I am finding myself stuck on one particular result that does not have a good reference in any literature. I am trying to prove weak Bezout - that any real algebraic plane curves have at most $\deg(f)\deg(g)$ points of intersection - as opposed to the version taking account for intersection multiplicities. I am also trying to avoid visiting the projective spaces.

There are several documents available online, most of which outline the same method of proof. Throughout $\mathrm{Res}(f,g,x)$ will denote the Sylvester resultant (i.e. the determinant of the relevant Sylvester matrix), and $\deg(f)$ (sans subscript) will denote the total degree of $f$.

A crucial step in proving the bound is to prove that for coprime bivariate polynomials $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ we have $$\deg_y\mathrm{Res}(f,g,x) \leq \deg(f)\deg(g) \tag{1}$$ This is actually most of the way towards Bezout.

In every proof I find online and in physical books however, the authors make an odd observation about the degrees of these polynomials. Suppose one writes as usual 
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(y)x^i$$
where $a_i(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$. Then the authors assert that $$\deg_y(a_i) \leq n-i \tag{2}$$ from which the proof of (1) follows easily by counting the degree of the determinant of the Sylvester matrix over all permutations. My issue is with the assumption that $\deg_y(a_i) \leq n-i$.

There seems to be two competing notions of how to write bivariate polynomials: one in which $n = \deg_x(f)$ and one in which $n = \deg(f)$. If we use the former then the bound (2) fails trivially by considering a polynomial such as $yx^2 + 2x + y$ as we should expect the coefficient of $x^2$ (i.e. $y$) to have degree 0.

If one instead more reasonably assumes that $n = \deg(f)$ then the bound indeed holds as we have by definition $\displaystyle\deg(f) = \max_{0\leq i \leq n} \{i+\deg(a_i)\}$. But then the resultant no longer has the property that $\mathrm{Res}(f,g,x) = 0 \iff f,g \text{ share a factor}$. To see this consider the polynomials
$$f(x,y) = yx^2 + yx + 1, \qquad g(x,y) = yx^2+x+2$$
Clearly $\deg(f) = \deg(g) = 3$, so to rewrite these in the form where we sum to the total degree we must write
$$f(x,y) = 0x^3 + yx^2 + yx + 1, \qquad g(x,y) = 0x^3 + yx^2+x+2$$

Then the appropriate Sylvester matrix is the 6x6 matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    y & 0 & 0 & t & 0 & 0 \\
    y & y & 0 & 1 & y & 0 \\
    1 & y & y & 2 & 1 & y \\
    0 & 1 & y & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
But this matrix has a zero row, so its determinant must be zero as well. But then the resultant is zero, despite the fact that the two polynomials are clearly coprime.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I did not make it clear why proof of (1) fails using $(\deg_x(f)+\deg_x(g)) \times (\deg_x(f)+\deg_x(g))$ with $n = \deg(f)$ (total degree).

Ideally, one would like to use some bound on each term in the Sylvester matrix, for instance
$$\deg(p_{ij}) \leq n+i-j, \deg(p_{ij}) \leq m+i-j$$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ or as Darij has done [in these comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068408/the-resultant-of-two-homogeneous-polynomials-is-homogeneous). This works perfectly fine if one assumes bound (2) with $n=\deg_x(f)$. However, this bound only works when we assume that we indeed have the bound $\deg_y(a_i) \leq \deg_x(f) - i$ as otherwise these methods give us a bound for (1) as $m\deg(f)+n\deg(g) - nm$. (n,m here are $\deg_x(f)$ and $\deg_x(g)$ respectively.) which (I think) isn't quite enough to prove what we want. It seems thus that the supposition that $\deg_y(a_i) \leq \deg_x(f) - i$ is crucial.

In particular it seems we need to have the dimensions of the matrix to coincide with the $n$ from bound (2). However if we try to extend the matrix to $(n+m) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ we end up with a zero row as above.

Comment: Where exactly does $n$ enter into the definition of the resultant?

Comment: Also, over an infinite field, you can use Noether normalization to ensure that $\deg_x f = \deg f$ (after a linear change of coordinates).

Comment: Your polynomials have degree 3, but when you compute their resultant as polynomials in $x$, well, as polynomials in $x$ they have degree 2.

Comment: Any thoughts, Nullsteller?

Comment: Are you still here, Nullsteller?

Comment: My sincerest apologies @GerryMyerson I have been unfortunately busy with family. I don't quite see how your hint fits in here, could you please expand? The bound $\deg(a_i) \leq n-i$ still fails as $n=\deg_x(f)=2$ would imply $\deg(a_2(y)) \leq 0$, but $a_2(y) = 1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg the resultant is the determinant of the $(n+m) \times (n+m)$ Sylvester matrix. Could you please provide a reference as to how Noether normalisation concerns polynomial degrees?

Comment: For the purposes of (2), $n=3$, the total degree. But when you compute the resultant as polynomials in $x$, each is a polynomial of degree 2. You don't want a $0x^3$ term, you don't want a $6\times6$ matrix, just a $4\times4$.

Comment: Actually, forget my comment. What I meant is that a "generic" linear substitution of variables $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(ax+by,cx+dy\right)$ (over a field of characteristic $0$) will result in a polynomial whose total degree is also its $x$-degree. But this substitution may easily mess up the resultant. Though, depending on the actual problem you're working on, it might still be okay.

Comment: @GerryMyerson please see my latest edit! I fear it is not very well written so please do feel free to ask questions.